# How can i host my website on amazon aws?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon

How can i host my website on amazon aws ??
i have two websites with two different domain names
for e.g www.webnil.com & www.security.com

so with two different domain names how can i host it using one amazon aws account

Comment: your question is better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: @Daniel A. White - I would say that it is better suited to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to host a whole website on amazon.  Only parts of it. For example. your global images and sprites, or your apps.  And Godaddy is not a good hosting service.  They are only good for domain regs.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you're going to need a bit of knowledge of administrating servers. If you don't have this, I would look at some sort of shared hosting or something like Media Temple's "[Grid Service](http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/gs/)".